# Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

Tags: flutter, gradle, kernel, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

This is my old project then was not supporting null safety then I enabled null safey and I upgraded my plugins, So I am trying to build this project app but getting this error.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM A505F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:186:20: Error: The argument type 'void Function(TapDownDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragDownDetails)?'.
 - 'TapDownDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap.dart').
 - 'TapDragDownDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
        onTapDown: onTapDown,
                   ^
/C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:190:24: Error: The argument type 'void Function(TapUpDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragUpDetails)?'.
 - 'TapUpDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap.dart').
 - 'TapDragUpDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
        onSingleTapUp: onSingleTapUp,
                       ^
/C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:195:26: Error: The argument type 'void Function(TapDownDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragDownDetails)?'.
 - 'TapDownDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap.dart').
 - 'TapDragDownDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
        onDoubleTapDown: onDoubleTapDown,
                         ^
/C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:196:31: Error: The argument type 'void Function(DragStartDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragStartDetails)?'.
 - 'DragStartDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
 - 'TapDragStartDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
        onDragSelectionStart: onDragSelectionStart,
                              ^
/C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:197:32: Error: The argument type 'void Function(DragStartDetails, DragUpdateDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragUpdateDetails)?'.
 - 'DragStartDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
 - 'DragUpdateDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
 - 'TapDragUpdateDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
        onDragSelectionUpdate: onDragSelectionUpdate,
                               ^
/C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/gesture_detector_builder.dart:198:29: Error: The argument type 'void Function(DragEndDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragEndDetails)?'.
 - 'DragEndDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
 - 'TapDragEndDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
        onDragSelectionEnd: onDragSelectionEnd,
                            ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1153

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 45s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

### This is my : gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-all.zip
```

### This is my : build-gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

### flutter doctor

```
C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 3.9.0-1.0.pre.120, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3448], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 3.9.0-1.0.pre.120 on channel master at C:\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 0d413e5d1a (8 months ago), 2023-03-09 04:17:11 -0500
    • Engine revision 54066d919a
    • Dart version 3.0.0 (build 3.0.0-312.0.dev)
    • DevTools version 2.22.2

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694)

[√] VS Code (version 1.82.3)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.72.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • SM A505F (mobile) • RZ8M42RXJ8H • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows     • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3448]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome      • web-javascript • Google Chrome 118.0.5993.89
    • Edge (web)        • edge        • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 117.0.2045.47

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
Process finished with exit code 0
```